# Specifying common plugin for all the subprojects in Gradle Multi Project Build

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an empty root project and one subproject

```
rootProject.name = "worder"
include("worder-core")
```

I want to make kotlin.jvm plugin to be common for all subprojects, build.gradle.kts(worder):

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.61" apply false
    id("idea")
}  

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
}
```

And then I'm trying to add dependencies to subproject, build.gradle.kts(worder-core):

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.3")
}
```

Okay, lets test it:

```
cd worder
gradle tasks // OK
cd worder-core
gradle tasks // FAILED -> Unresolved reference: implementation
```

So, why do I have worder-core project configuration failed ? IDEA doesn't complain at all.

[full root build script](https://gist.github.com/Evgen25176542/942cf72f6f498c44cc99e0c2681dda3a)

[full subproject build sript](https://gist.github.com/Evgen25176542/a4ff5c79f902787ad6505a273f3a481f)

Comment: what version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Gradle 6.1

Comment: It works fine for me using your build scripts and using Gradle 6.1. Do you have a stray settings.gradle.kts in your sub-project? If so, that would make Gradle think it is a stand-alone project when invoking Gradle from that directory.

Comment: @BjørnVester yes, so it is. but it's still confusing, because this redundant setting.gradle.kts is not honored by IDEA. Thank you!